# positioning the cursor

Tags: functionality

Whenever I type a SMS or an email or anything on a text field, I find it difficult to position the cursor at my desired place. Its easy to place by the end or beginning, but not in the middle of the word. Are there any mouse position keys ( left right keys ) or any other trick I am missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you push on text until cursor appears, then position cursor by moving the finger.

Comment: yes I get that. But the challenge is to place the exactly where I want specially its long word. Its like try until you succeed.

Comment: @franklins: I find it very easy, as the cursor appears above your finger, not under it.

Comment: woah now I get it really well.. I have to wait for the blue cursor and scroll down, so that the cursor is on the word.. then its really easy... Thank you Oleg and Paradroid...

Comment: Actually @franklins I think the cursor is the same color as your accent color. Is it?

Comment: o.. ye .. i didnt realize that till then..., well now you know my current theme color..